# Подскажите по параметрам из keyspace в redis

Tags: redis

В выводе команды `redis-cli info keyspace` выводится значение `expires` и `avg_ttl` для каждой из имеющихся баз redis. Что означают эти параметры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expires` - количество ключей, которые истекают в какой-то момент в будущем.

`avg_ttl` - оценка средней продолжительности жизни ключей в миллисекундах, основанная на случайном выборе ключей

Comment: Если expires=0,avg_ttl=0 то это значит что все ключи в базе никогда не устареют и не будут удалены? Можно ли как то глобально влиять на время устаревания ключей в базе?

Comment: те что попали под рассмотрение, да